# How to build CMake Debug version using different target name for executables?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

I am building using `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .`.

And I am using `set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)` to add a `d` to the end of the filename.

This is working for static libraries and I expected it to work for executables as well. But, at least in my case, it is compiling all the static libraries using `*d.a` and the executable without `d` suffix.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not missing anything. As the documentation says (emphasis mine):

> When a **non-executable target** is created its `<CONFIG>_POSTFIX` target property is initialized with the value of this variable if it is set.

See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CONFIG_POSTFIX.html

By the sounds of it, though, you could manually set the property on your executable target with `set_target_properties`:

```
set_target_properties(
  target1 ... targetN
  PROPERTIES
  DEBUG_POSTFIX "${CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX}"
)
```

Note, however, that it doesn't apply to executables by default because that's rarely what you want. For libraries, it's fairly common to package and deploy debug and release configurations simultaneously. On Windows, for development, it is a requirement. On the other hand, one very rarely needs to deploy debug applications and hence one very rarely wants a postfix applied.

Comment: Thank you very much! That explains it well. I just have a question. Do I need to write `PROPERTIES`? Or is it simply a dummy text for properties? And I personally like to have a different filename for debug version, so that I can easily see which one is the release version for publishing :)

Comment: @Z0q - yes you do need `PROPERTIES`. It separates the list of target names from the pairs of property-value arguments. See the documentation for `set_target_properties`, here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html

Comment: Alright, thank you! Should I add it after `add_executable()`, like `target_compile_definitions()`?

Comment: @Z0q - I think you mean `set_target_properties`? In either case, yes. Both those commands require the target(s) to have been declared already.